# Dirac Delta potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, dirac-delta-distributions, quantum-tunneling

As we know a particle in attractive Dirac delta potential has discontinuity in the derivative of its wavefunction.

I have two questions in this regard:

1. Can a second-order differential equation (the [TISE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation)) be still defined when the first-order derivative is discontinuous at some point?
2. How can we justify $E<0$ for bound state when a particle in an attractive Dirac-delta potential will be confined to a single point?

Comment: A _classical_ particle will be confined to a single point. A wavefunction describing a quantum particle will not.

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes, see [weak solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_solution).
2. The wave function doesn't have to vanish in classically forbidden regions, cf. [quantum tunnelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_tunnelling).

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to deal with the Dirac potential ($V(x)=\lambda\delta(x)$):

- Schrödinger equation is local and still valid everywhere, except for the point where the potential is located ($x=0$). We thus can solve it everywhere and replace the potential with an approrpiate boundary conditions at $x=0$ (which are easily derived as the continuity of the wave function and a jump of its second derivative, proportional to the potentail strength.)
- Consider a square well of depth and width satisfying $V_0w=\lambda$, solve the Schrödinger equation and take the limit of the infinite well - the SE will be well defined, and one merely studies the asymptotic behavior of the solution. In case one does not like rectangualr well with abrapt boundaries, it is possible to use any smooth function converging to a delta-function (Lorentz curve, Gaussian, etc.)